# Como alinhar os ícones com os textos ao lado no Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Então, gostaria de saber como posso deixar os ícones alinhados com os textos, no caso, o texto bem na direção do centro do ícone. Eu tentei assim, e com algumas outras classes do Bootstrap, mas algumas nem surtem efeito.

```
<div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-start align-items-stretch">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="logo-email"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 m1-auto align-self-center">
                                    <p class="texto-estilo">texto aqui</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Mas dessa forma eles não se alinham, o texto sempre fica muito pra cima, ou muito para baixo, está estranho. No momento esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você pode postar um fiddle de como esta para te ajudar melhor?

Comment: claro, just a sec

Comment: ah, na verdade não sei como fazer com o bootstrap lá no jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código na verdade tem vários problemas com relação o Bootstrap. Primeiro que o pai de uma `col-` deve ser uma `row`, depois que a classe `m1-auto` não existe, acredito que vc queria escrever `m-1`. Depois que para usar as classe de flexbox tipo `align-self-center` o container tem que ser flex, e a `col-` não é flex, então vc precisa colocar na `col-` algo como  `<div class="col-md-8 m-3 d-flex align-items-center">`

Agora uma dica, o tag `<p>` por padrão tem um `margin-botton`, algo que vc não quer! Então coloque nele `m-0` isso vai zerar as margens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o sem modelo alinhado, apenas com as classes no Bootstrap! Não precisa de CSS extra! **OBS:** Mudei as configs das `col-` apenas para demonstrar aqui no Snippet, mas no seu documento vc pode voltar para `col-md-`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 m-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="logo-email"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 m-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <p class="texto-estilo m-0">texto aqui</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso foi perfeito. Obrigado hugo, estava bem confuso mesmo para mim. Isso resolveu.

Comment: @GiovaneMachado tranquilo meu caro, sempre que precisar que uma col- seja flex basta colocar nela a classe d-flex, depois vc pode usar as demais classes do flexbox para alinhar as coisas dentro dela... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 2):

Veja esta solução:
https://jsfiddle.net/gferreiraa/7ty6o5zL/3/

```
<div class="container">

    <span class="d-block">
    <span>texto aqui</span>
    <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="logo-email"></i>
    </span>

    </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Getulio!

Comment: Valeu @GiovaneMachado! Disponha!